# BluemixのWatsonサービスにおける機械学習機能

Tags: bluemix, watson-api

Bluemix上のWatson関連のサービスで機械学習そのものをさせることが可能なサービスはありますでしょうか?Documentを確認したのですが、サービスの内容とAPIの利用方法が書かれているのみのものが多く、実際に機械学習させる方法に関しての記述が無さそうでした。

たとえばVisual Recognition等で特定の人物の画像認識をさせるように機械学習させるようなことは可能でしょうか?

http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/services-catalog.html

Answer (score 1):

Visual Recognition には学習させる機能はなさそうです。
ただ NLC(Natual Language Classifier)では自分の作った辞書で（日本語を）学習させた上でテキストの分類を行う、といったことはできます。